# Why am I getting 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'value' referenced'?

Tags: python

I just learned what classes are today so I'm hoping this doesn't look too bad. 'model' refers to the model year.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, model=0, price=0, year=0):
       self.model = model
       self.price = price
       self.year = year

    def depreciate(self, price):
        rate = 0.15
        age = da_car.model - da_car.year
        for i in range(age):
            value = price * rate
            price = value
        return value

    def print_info(self):
        print('Car\'s infortmation: \n  Model year: ', da_car.model ,' \n  Purchase price:  ', da_car.price,' \n  Current value: ', car_value)


da_car = Car()

da_car.model = int(input())
da_car.price = int(input())
da_car.year = int(input())


car_value = da_car.depreciate(da_car.price)

da_car.print_info()
```

I'm trying to return the depreciated value of the input price after x amount of years. Not sure why I'm getting this error. I tried making 'value' global but that did not work.

Comment: Hint: What happens when `age` is `<= 0`?

Comment: You are using `da_car`, a global variable, where you want to use the method parameter `self` in the definition of your methods.

Comment: `age` should also be `self.year - self.model`, as it doesn't make sense to ask the age of a car in a year before it is released.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the variable "value" actually is defined within the "for" loop, and that is its scope.  So that variable and its information is not known outside of that loop.  The program would most likely want/need a definition of that variable that would be visible within the class.  With that in mind and testing out the code I made a few tweaks to the program.  Following is a revised version of your program.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, model=0, price=0.0, year=0):
       self.model = model
       self.price = price
       self.year  = year
       self.value = price               # This will be calculated later

    def depreciate(self):
        rate = 0.15
        age = self.year - self.model    # Correct age calculation
        self.value = self.price         # Initialize the value to the initial price
        for i in range(age):
            self.value = float(self.value - self.value * rate)
            #price = value
        return self.value

    def print_info(self):
        # The function within a method would not print data for a specific class (e.g. "da_car")
        print('Car\'s infortmation: \n  Model year: ', self.model ,' \n  Purchase price:  ', self.price,' \n  Current value: ', self.value)

da_car = Car()
dx_car = Car()

print("First car statistics")

da_car.model = int(input("Model year: "))
da_car.price = float(input("Price: "))
da_car.year = int(input("Current year: "))

car_value = da_car.depreciate()

da_car.print_info()

print("Second car statistics")

dx_car.model = int(input("Model year: "))
dx_car.price = float(input("Price: "))
dx_car.year = int(input("Current year: "))

car_value = dx_car.depreciate()

dx_car.print_info()
```

Following are some key points.

- In order to make the value variable pertinent to the depreciation function and to the car printing function, it was added as an attribute to the class.
- In the various class functions, it would not be appropriate to use object specific variables in the calculations; rather class defined variables make more sense - so references to a specific object were changed to the "self" reference.
- In testing I noticed the calculation for age was incorrect - the two variables needed to be reversed.
- A second object definition was added to accentuate the point of usage of classes and objects and attempt to clarify why one would not want to use object specific variables in a class function.

With those revisions in place, a test run of the program was done.

```
@Dev:~/Python_Programs/Cars$ python3 Cars.py 
First car statistics
Model year: 2020
Price: 32000
Current year: 2025
Car's infortmation: 
  Model year:  2020  
  Purchase price:   32000.0  
  Current value:  14198.57
Second car statistics
Model year: 2018
Price: 44000
Current year: 2025
Car's infortmation: 
  Model year:  2018  
  Purchase price:   44000.0  
  Current value:  14105.391884375002
```

Some print formatting would be beneficial for the current value but this should highlight the setup and use of objects based upon class definitions.

Give that a try and see if it meets the spirit of your project.